# Catch spring transaction exception in service

Tags: spring, spring-transactions

i'd like to catch spring transaction exception in service layer not in the service heighr layer or the service caller.
As i found i can not catch the exception in the @transaction method.i need to take an action once the the transaction failes in the same method or the same  service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transaction is rolled back when exception is thrown from method annotated with @Transactional (or class can be annotated with @Transactional).

So you can't do post rollback actions in this method. If you want to do this logic on service layer, you can have service bean handling post rollback action call another service bean which handles transaction.

Comment: Thanks @luboskrnac but i'd like to handle the rollback action in the sane Service bean which will responsible about particular business process. Creating two separate service for the same business process is not  good.